# How to change the color of the close icon of a SearchView?

Tags: android

Meaning the X icon that appears after you click the search icon of a SearchView. I'm using the default close icon provided in the SearchView.

I did this in the app theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Other items -->
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="closeIconTint">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

And it's not working. Adding other items into `MySearchViewStyle` works, it's just `closeIconTint` that seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the colour of close icon of an androidX SearchView (androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView) programmatically like below:

```
searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

ImageView searchClose = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(searchClose, ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)));
```

or in Xml you can use the **app:closeIcon** attribute and set a white vector drawable like below:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
   android:id="@+id/searchView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"
   android:textSize="14sp"
   app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"/>
```

where **@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp** is a white vector drawable like below:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z"/>
</vector>
```

And the Result for both approach with a white close icon colour is like below:

[image: SearchView Close White Icon]